# Multiple definitions with SimpleJSON library (C++)

Tags: c++, linker, simplejson, multiple-definition-error

I am writing a program in C++ using SimpleJSON as the JSON library of my choice, and have ran into a weird bug, where the following (quite simple) files generate tons of error messages while being linked:

jsonobject.hpp:

```
#ifndef _JSONOBJECT
#define _JSONOBJECT

#include "../../lib/simplejson/json.hpp"

int foo();

#endif
```

jsonobject.cpp:

```
#include "jsonobject.hpp"

int foo()
{
   return 0;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "jsonobject.hpp"

int main()
{
    return foo();
}
```

The error messages (I am using `g++ *.cpp -std=c++11` for compiling):

```
/tmp/ccMoY6Vl.o: In function `json::Array()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1cd): multiple definition of `json::Array()'
/tmp/ccjd4YF7.o:jsonobject.cpp:(.text+0x1cd): first defined here
/tmp/ccMoY6Vl.o: In function `json::Object()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x23e): multiple definition of `json::Object()'
/tmp/ccjd4YF7.o:jsonobject.cpp:(.text+0x23e): first defined here
/tmp/ccMoY6Vl.o: In function `json::operator<<(std::ostream&, json::JSON const&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2af): multiple definition of `json::operator<<(std::ostream&, json::JSON const&)'
/tmp/ccjd4YF7.o:jsonobject.cpp:(.text+0x2af): first defined here
/tmp/ccMoY6Vl.o: In function `json::JSON::Load(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a0c): multiple definition of `json::JSON::Load(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/tmp/ccjd4YF7.o:jsonobject.cpp:(.text+0x1a0c): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this the fault of the SimpleJSON library ([Here it is on GitHub](https://github.com/nbsdx/SimpleJSON/))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem with the SimpleJSON library you are using.  A quick look at json.hpp confirms it defines several namespace-scope non-template functions in the header file without marking them `inline`.  This makes it impossible to include the header from multiple translation units, which seriously reduces how it can be used.

This has already been reported [on SimpleJSON's git issue tracker](https://github.com/nbsdx/SimpleJSON/issues/4). It looks like at least one person has attempted and committed a fix on a personal branch, but it has not yet been pulled to the main branch.  You might be able to get code from that branch to try it out.

Comment: I'm gonna try it later today, thank you for the tip.

Comment: Update: 2021 the issue is still present. So I would rather look for alternatives. In it's current state it's unusable.

Answer (score 2):

The author repository has been archived. It is now read-only.
So I could not create pull request or comment on the original issue board.

I have found a solution splitting in two files as follow:
https://github.com/andakkino/SimpleJSON

I've created a json.cpp file with this content

```
#include <json.hpp>

using namespace  json;

JSON JSON::Load( const string &str ) {
    size_t offset = 0;
    return std::move( parse_next( str, offset ) );
}
```

in the .hpp files I add "inline" in some functions and, obviusly, eliminated Load Function